# Section 4.3 Exercise #5 - "Think Python" by Allen Downey

Tags: python, function, turtle-graphics

Link to the Exercises can be accessed here - [Case Study: Interface Design, Exercise Section 4.3](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython005.html#toc42)

Quoting the question, it seems I have to implement an `arc()` function:

> Make a more general version of `circle` called `arc` that takes an additional parameter `angle`, which determines what fraction of a circle to draw. `angle` is in units of degrees, so when angle=360, `arc` should draw a complete circle.

The code I've written so far:

```
import turtle
import math
bob = turtle.Turtle()

def polygon(t, n, length):
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(length)
        t.lt(360/n)

def circle(t, r):
    circumference = 2 * math.pi * r
    n = int(circumference/3) + 1
    length = circumference/n
    polygon(t, n, length)

def arc(t, r, angle):
    arc_length = 2 * math.pi * r * (angle/360)
    n = (arc_length/4) + 1

arc(bob, 1000, 45)

turtle.mainloop()
```

I'm intending to call the `circle()` function within `arc()` just as `polygon()` was called within `circle()`, but I'm confused on how I should do that. Apart from that, the `arc()` function *does not* draw anything, rather just shows me a stationary Turtle.

I believe that the Turtle object `bob` isn't receiving any of the movement instructions assigned within `polygon()`. Thus all that it's doing is displaying the Turtle object!

I could be wrong, and this where I need clarification. Should I call `circle()` within `arc()` as well as make the Turtle object move? Are there easier alternatives? Calling functions within a function is still confusing for me, so more resources to learn about them would be great as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to ... call the circle() function
>   within arc() just as polygon() was called within circle()

You've got this backward.  The problem states:

> Make a more general version of circle called arc

Just as you could draw a circle with the more general function `polygon()`, you should be able to draw a circle with the more general function `arc()`.  Here's a skeletal program for thinking about this:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from math import pi

def polygon(turtle, sides, length):
    outside_angle = 360 / sides

    for _ in range(sides):
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(outside_angle)

def circle_using_polygon(turtle, radius):
    circumference = 2 * pi * radius
    sides = min(60, int(circumference / 3))
    length = circumference / sides
    polygon(turtle, sides, length)

def arc(turtle, radius, angle):
    # implement arc not by calling *circle() nor by
    # calling polygon() but rather by borrowing code
    # from both and adding one more step to reduce
    # the number of sides based on the arc angle

def circle_using_arc(turtle, radius):
    arc(turtle, radius, 360)

bob = Turtle(visible=False)

# Draw overlapping circles three different ways:

bob.color("green")
circle_using_polygon(bob, 100)

for color in ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'black']:
    bob.color(color)
    arc(bob, 100, 90)

bob.color("blue")
circle_using_arc(bob, 100)

screen = Screen()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes a lot more sense now. I see that you've made use of explicit names for the parameters, that's something I need to work on as well. Also really appreciate for making the necessary edits with the question, I was afraid my question would be downvoted again and I would be blocked from asking further queries. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
import turtle
bob=turtle.Turtle()
import math
def arc(t,radius,angle):
    circumference = 2.0*math.pi*radius
    frac = angle/360.0
    arclength = circumference*frac
    n = 50 # pick a number
    len = arclength/n;
    turnang = angle/n
    for i in range(n):
        t.fd(len)
        t.lt(turnang)
arc(bob, 130,360)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Simple and clever answer. Very useful

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter
import swampy
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *

def polygon(n, t, length, angle):
    print(t)
    k= angle/360
    for i in range(0,int(n*k)):
        fd(t, length)
        p= 360
        lt(t,p/n)
        t.delay
world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()
#def circle(r):
    #l1= 2*3.14*r
    #l= l1/60
    #polygon(30, bob, l)

polygon(60, bob, 10, 180)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. It's just a dump of code. Please explain what is happening in the code for the OP to have an understanding of what to do